# Proving the symmetry of natural numbers

Tags: coq

I am a beginner in coq. I want to prove symmetry of a boolean equality on natural numbers. I have applied induction and destruct commands, but it does not work. Please guide me in proving the theorem.

```
Fixpoint  beqnat(n m : nat): bool:= 
  match n with 
  |0=> match m with
      |0=> true
      |S m' => false
      end 
  |S n'=> match m with
         |0=>false
         |S m'=> beqnat n' m'
         end  
  end. 

  Theorem beq sys:  
    forall(n m:nat), 
      beqnat n m = beqnat m n.
```

Comment: It would help if you could link to an executable example at https://x80.org/collacoq/

Comment: Would it be feasible to use the standard library or do you want to prove this fact as an exercise?

Comment: I want to prove it as an exercise,because I have studied the chapter about induction and destruct command, this is the exercise question of that chapter.Therefore I think it should prove by same tactics.

Comment: Can you then please update the question by adding the proof you have so far and explaining where you struggle? That way we can easier help you.

Comment: Theorem beqnatrefl : forall n :,beq_n n= true.
Proof.
intros n.
induction n [n IH].
simpl. reflexivity.

simpl. reflexivity.
Qed.
Theorem eq-beq-nat : forall n1 n2,n1n = n2 -> beq-nat n1 n2 = true.
Proof.
intros n1 n2 H.
rewrite H.
rewrite beqnatrefl.
reflexivity.
Qed.

Comment: @sana sobia: please don't forget to accept an answer or add a comment explaining why it does not address your question.

Answer (score 2):

The proof follows by induction on `n` followed by destruction on `m`:

```
Theorem beq_sym: forall n m : nat, beqnat n m = beqnat m n.
Proof.
  induction n as [|n' IH]; destruct m; auto.
  apply IH.
Qed.
```

To understand what is happening:

1. Do `induction n` which gives subgoals for `n = 0` and `n = S n'`.
2. Do `simpl` on each subgoal to see how the first `match/with` reduces.
3. Now you need to do something to `m` to reduce the second `match/with`. Induction is not necessary because your `beqnat` is structurally recursive on `n` (type `Print beqnat` and look for `{struct n}` to confirm), not `m`. So, `destruct m` suffices. Again, use `simpl` to see why.
4. The induction hypothesis is needed for the recursive call to `beqnat` in the second subgoal.